# Win32 C++17 - Pointer returned by system_category().message().c_str() dies immediately...why?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, scope, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main() {
    // ...many lines of code not related to the problem

    auto errMsg = system_category().message(GetLastError()).c_str();
    char buf[MAX_PATH];

    // Throws an access violation exception
    StringCchPrintfA(buf, MAX_PATH, "Function '%s' failed: %s", "main", errMsg);

    // ...more unrelated code
}
```

I've been pulling my hair out for over an hour trying to figure out why on Earth this stupid exception was being thrown. Then I finally decided to consult you fine folks about it, and found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833682/contents-changedcleared-when-access-the-pointer-returned-by-stdstringc-st#answer-2833747) that explains it pretty clearly:

> The temporary returned by the conf() function call lives as long as the full expression it is part of, not for the length of the function containing the call.

Of course I'm not calling the same function as that question's OP, but I'm guessing the reason for my failure is the same. But I've never encountered this problem before in **over 18 years** of programming! So could someone kindly explain why exactly the value returned from the `message()` function is only temporary, and unable to be relied upon? And more to the point: **how do I fix it?**

MTIA! :-)

EDIT: Just realised that I could use `FormatMessage()` instead, but I'd still like an explanation of this behaviour please. Thanks!

Comment: You're getting temporary string value, so it's destructed at the end of expression.

Comment: The `std::string` (presumably) returned by `system_category().message(GetLastError())` ceases to exist at the end of the statement. So the call of `c_str()` is giving a pointer to data, managed by an object that immediately ceases to exist.   Calling `c_str()` doesn't magically extend the life of the returned `std::string`.    Instead, save the string in another variable, and call `c_str()` on that variable  (e.g.  `std::string catMsg = system_category().message(GetLastError());  auto errMsg = catMsg.c_str();`.    `catMsg will exist until the enclosing scope (`{}`) ends, and so will `errMsg`.

Comment: If you have been coding this way for 18 years, then you have probably left bugs for other people to fix after you have moved on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have the same issue as the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833682/). In this case, `message()` is returning a *temporary* `std::string` object **by value**, which goes out of scope and is destroyed on the `;` at the end of the statement that creates it.  You are taking a pointer to the temporary's internal data, then the temporary is destroyed before you have a chance to use that pointer, causing **Undefined Behavior** when you try to use that pointer to access invalid memory.

The fact that you have been coding this way for 18 years is very troubling.  You should have encountered this a long time ago.

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. extend the scope of the data by saving the temporary `std::string` object to a variable BEFORE you grab a pointer to its data:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main() {
    // ...many lines of code not related to the problem

    auto errMsg = system_category().message(GetLastError()); // <-- not c_str()!
    char buf[MAX_PATH];

    StringCchPrintfA(buf, MAX_PATH, "Function '%s' failed: %s", "funcName", errMsg.c_str()); // <-- use c_str() here!

    // ...more unrelated code
}
```

2. use the temporary `std::string` and its data pointer directly in the `StringCchPrintfA()` statement, so the temporary stays in scope:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main() {
    // ...many lines of code not related to the problem

    char buf[MAX_PATH];
    StringCchPrintfA(buf, MAX_PATH, "Function '%s' failed: %s", "funcName", system_category().message(GetLastError()).c_str());

    // ...more unrelated code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now. As for your suggestions, I tried both before posting and neither helped. The latter one was actually my very first attempt at this, since I've always been an avid code golfer :P

Comment: Also I'd like to clarify what I said about "18 years of programming". Not all of that was spent coding in C/C++, in fact probably only a year or so was, and that was as a student. Still, I too find it hard to believe that I've never encountered this problem before. Perhaps I have and just don't remember.

Comment: @Kenny83 "*I tried both before posting and neither helped*" - then you did something wrong with them, because both approaches work fine when used *correctly*.

Comment: I stand corrected! I must have tried a slight variation of your latter example, as it seemed to be the same at first glance but copying it verbatim into my project worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!

Comment: One last thing before I leave you in peace: do you know of a way to reliably do this with wide strings? It seems as though `system_category().message()` was not written with multiple charsets in mind...

Comment: @Kenny83 Not with the standard C++ classes, no. You will just have to write your wrapper that converts a system error code into a `std::wstring`, such as via the Win32 `FormatMessageW()` function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the function message returns a temporary object of the type `std::string` (or `std::basic_string`). The pointer returned by the member function `c_str` is valid while the temporary object is alive.

One of methods to avoid the undefined behavior is to store the returned string like for example

```
auto errMsg = system_category().message(GetLastError());
```

and then to use the expression `errMsg.c_str()` if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the type of your `auto errMsg`? I bet it's `const char*`, to the. possibly, dead string